# PowerShell, How to provide a pipe variable?

Tags: powershell, object, pipe, pscustomobject

This is a high level question as the details might not be precise, as I'm not in my office but home.

I have a function that accept variables through pipe:

```
get-csv | myfunc
```

The pipe source is the fields from a .csv file.

How to define a variables and pipe into `myfunc()`? Would `HashTable` be good?

```
$my_pipe_variables = @{ Color = ‘Red’; Doors = 4; Convertible = $false}
$my_pipe_variables | myfunc
```

would that be the correct syntax?

**Update:**

I finally get around to try it but it is not working for me, as my `myfunc` accesses pipe variables directly via `$_`. Here is the demo:

```
function showThem { echo Color: $_.Color }

> [pscustomobject]@{ Color = ‘Red’; Doors = 4; Convertible = $false} | showThem
Color:
```

How can I make it works for `myfunc`, which accesses pipe variables directly via `$_`?

Comment: @mklement0, my only intent is to replace reading from .csv to providing from variable, all the rests are shooting into the dark. Please ignore and show me the correct way of doing it, for sample .csv input of `Color = ‘Red’; Doors = 4; Convertible = $false`. thx.

Comment: Instead of piping, you can use the hashtable for [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6#splatting-with-hash-tables) the parameters to your function. P.s. get rid of the curly 'smart-quotes' and use straight ones.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Theo. It might not suit my specific case as my `myfunc()` access pipe variables directly via `$_.`, instead of defining `Param`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Import-Csv`** (not `Get-Csv`), for reading CSV data from a *file*, and **`ConvertFrom-Csv`**, for reading CSV data from a *string*, **output a collection of *custom objects* (type `[pscustomobject]`)** whose properties reflect the CSV data's columns.

To construct such custom objects on demand in order to ***simulate* `Import-Csv` / `ConvertFrom-Csv` input**, use the 
`[pscustomobject] @{ <propertyName>=<value>; ... }` syntax (PSv3+).

E.g., to simulate 2 rows of CSV data with columns `Color`, `Doors`, 
 and `Convertible`:

```
[pscustomobject] @{ Color = 'Red'; Doors = 4; Convertible = $false },
[pscustomobject] @{ Color = 'Blue'; Doors = 5; Convertible = $false } |
  ...
```

---

Separately, **in order to make a function process input from the pipeline *object by object* via automatic variable `$_`, it must have a `process { ...}` block** - see help topic [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions#piping-objects-to-functions).

```
# Define the function body with a process { ... } block, which
# PowerShell automatically calls for each input object from the pipeline,
# reflected in automatic variable $_
function showThem { process { "Color: " + $_.Color } }

[pscustomobject] @{ Color = 'Red'; Doors = 4; Convertible = $false },
[pscustomobject] @{ Color = 'Blue'; Doors = 5; Convertible = $false } |
  showThem
```

<sup>Note: In PowerShell, `echo` is an alias of `Write-Output`, whose explicit use is rarely needed; instead, the function relies on PowerShell's *implicit output*: the result of the string concatenation (`+`) implicitly becomes the function's output.</sup>

The above yields:

```
Color: Red
Color: Blue
```